# How can I pass get_the_author_meta('user_email') through the REST API?

Tags: plugin-development, ajax, page-template, email, rest-api

In my plugin if I hard code an email address in my function with either `wp_mail()` or `mail()` I can get my form to work:

```
function email_form($ip_address, $agent, $referrer, $email, $name, $message) {
    $to         = "darthvader@wpse.com";
    $subject    = "Hard Coded";
    $email_body = 
        "IP ADDRESS: "  . $ip_address   . "\n" . 
        "USER AGENT: "  . $agent        . "\n\n" .
        "EMAIL: "       . $email        . "\n" .
        "NAME: "        . $name         . "\n" .
        "MESSAGE: "     . $message      . "\n";
    mail("$to", "$subject", "$email_body", "From: $email");
}
```

However, when I try to add the email based on the author with:

```
$to = get_the_author_meta('user_email');
```

from a `global $post;` it will not send the email.

If I build a function at the beginning of the template and set a variable I can get the author to fire but I think this approach is incorrect.  I can build a setting page but I want the recipient to be the author of the page. 
 In a page template that sends the processing to another PHP file what is the proper way to pass the author's email  of the page post type or any other WP related data (`the_title()`, theme, etc. etc) through `WP_REST_Request`?

---

**EDIT:**

After finding out I should go `wp_localize_script` I authored:

```
function foobar() {
    if (is_page_template('page-foo.php')) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'bar_js', site_url() . '/js/bar.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
        $localized = array(
            'url_string'    => site_url(),
            'form_id'       => get_the_ID(),
            'author_email'  => get_the_author_meta('user_email', get_post_field('post_author', get_the_ID())),
        );
        wp_localize_script('bar_js', 'form_object', $localized);
    };
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'foobar');
```

and passed in `bar.js`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    console.log('file is being detected'); // FOR TESTING
    console.log(form_object.author_email);
});
```

but is there a better way to call the author email outside of the loop in this manner?

Comment: What's the context here? Who is the author you're trying to get, the author of the post the form is on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why I Don't Have Access to Post's Information?

When you are using Admin-AJAX or the REST API, you will only have access to the current user's data (by that I mean by default, such as using `is_user_logged_in()`). To retrieve any other information, you have to pass it as an argument in your AJAX request. WordPress will not load the whole stuff in an AJAX request, so you have to find a workaround.

### Using Hidden Inputs:

Since you don't have access to any post-related information (such as the post's ID), and approach would be to include a hidden input and add the extra data to it:

```
<input id="my-hidden-input" type="hidden" value="User ID Here" />
```

This goes anywhere in your `page.php` file. Now you can fetch it by using this simple jQuery command:

```
var userId = $('#my-hidden-input').val();
```

### Localizing the Script:

There is a better alternative to do this, and it's by using [`wp_localize_script()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script). Let's say you are enqueuing your main JS file as follows:

```
wp_enqueue_script('my-js-handle','some/path/here.js');
```

You can pass the necessary data to your JS file, by localizing it. For example, we need to pass the post's ID. We can do so by creating a conditional and localizing our script:

```
if( is_page() ){
    $localization_array(
        'post_id' => get_the_ID(),
    );
    wp_localize_script( 'my-js-handle', 'my_object_name', $localization_array, )'
}
```

Now we can access the post's ID in our script as simple as this:

```
window.alert( my_object_name.post_id );
```

### Some Notes:

- You should have an enqueued JS file to use the second method
- The handle name of the localized script must be the same as enqueued script
- You should localize your script *"before"* you enqueue it

Comment: Ah I totally forgot about `wp_localize_script`.  I can pass other information with this, excellent.  Will test later tonight and let you know.

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ Haha finally found one of your questions on homepage!

Comment: The problem with your edit is... _"Which author?"_? You are outside the loop. There is no author there.

Comment: the author of the page template is what I'm after.  It pulls the author when I `console.log` but I dont know if that is the proper approach outside the loop.